# Transaction working in remix but not errored from dapp

Tags: web3js, remix, dapps, react, solidity-0.5.x

I have a master contract which deploys instances of other contracts.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract DataEntityContract {


    DataEntity DE;

    constructor(string memory _name,string[] memory _relatedEntities, string memory _date, string memory _fileName, string memory _annotations) public
    {
        DE = DataEntity(_name, 'URN', _fileName, new string[](0), _relatedEntities, 'references', _annotations, msg.sender, _date);
    }

    struct DataEntity {
        //Event notifications;
        string dataEntityName;
        string rawFileURN;
        string fileName;
        string[] nameChangeHistory;
        string[] sources;
        string references;
        string annotations;
        address createdUpdateBy;
        string when;
    }

    function editDE() public {
        DE.annotations = "edited";
    }

    function getAnnotations() public view returns(string memory) {
        return (DE.annotations);
    }

}

contract FlattenedDEC
{
    address owner;
    string public name;
    mapping (string => address) dataEntities;
    string[] public dataEntityNames;
    uint count = 0;
    uint public DataEntitiesCount = 0;
    mapping(uint => Lineage) public lineageInfo;
    mapping(uint => DE) public DataEntities;

    event DataEntityEdited(
        string name,
        string comments,
        address editedBy
    );

    constructor() public
    {
        name = "DataEntityCatalogue Master Contract";
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function createNewDataEntity(string memory _name, string[] memory _dataEntities, string memory _date, string memory _fileName, string memory _annotations) public returns(address _new){
        DataEntityContract instance = new DataEntityContract(_name,_dataEntities, _date, _fileName, _annotations);
        return address(instance);
    }

    function editDE(string memory _name) public{
        DataEntityContract de = DataEntityContract(dataEntities[_name]);
        de.editDE();
        emit DataEntityEdited(_name, "edited", msg.sender);
    }
```

Now, when I try to call the editDE method in FlattenedDEC or even in DataEntityContract from my dapp I am gettting a jsonrpc error but when I call the same from remix everything works fine.

Here is my react js code:

```
async editDataEntity(name){
    const web3 = window.web3;
    const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
    const networkData = await FlattenedDEC.networks[networkId];
    const contract = web3.eth.Contract(FlattenedDEC.abi, networkData.address);
    contract.methods.editDE().send({from: this.state.account})
    .on('error',(error) => {
      console.log("error: ", error);
    })
    .on('transactionHash', () => {
      console.log("edited");
    });
  }
```

This is the error i get:

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload 
{"id":6402969023659,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":
["0xf9010e8203dc85746a528800836170d494ca9a565e46004c9e5f9b2ac2b4ca83d61814c20180b
8a4108770750000000000000060000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064544495
445440000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000822d45a0186aa938713cc78d
fe0089d896b0890ffa693ad77fe521d4d3e5e454d2fbe600a045413f6b3d94d1df175ba42e7790e99
9fe3a97a44c91451632abb02789e10612"],
"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"}
```

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":6402969023659,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["0xf9010e8203dc85746a528800836170d494ca9a565e46004c9e5f9b2ac2b4ca83d61814c20180b8a4108770750000000000000060000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064544495445440000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000822d45a0186aa938713cc78dfe0089d896b0890ffa693ad77fe521d4d3e5e454d2fbe600a045413f6b3d94d1df175ba42e7790e999fe3a97a44c91451632abb02789e10612"],"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"}

Comment: @vteja711 Please edit your question and add the error message there so it can get formatted properly. Are you testing against a ganache, a private testnet or a public testnet?

Comment: Edited with the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

Turns out that whenever this error occurs it is because we are sending the contract some wierd data. So in my case I was not sending proper parameters and was sending an empty name. This took a lot of deugging to come to this conclusion. This actually solved a couple more problems for me.

So, information is that whenever someone gets this error, please check the values that are being passed to the contract methods.